# Objective-C passing values from NSView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsarray, sender

I'm new to Objective-C and I'm struggling to find the proper way to pass NSArray values from one NSView to another NSView. My code looks like this:

*NSViewOne:*

```
NSLog(@"%@", arrayValues); // 10, 20, 30
NSViewTwo *displayValues = [[NSViewTwo alloc] init];
[displayValues showValuesFromOne:arrayValues];
```

*NSViewTwo:*

```
- (void)showValuesFromOne:(NSArray *)sender {
     NSArray *arrayValues = sender;
     NSLog(@"%@", arrayValues);
}
```

In NSViewOne the array values show, in NSViewTwo I get (null).

Comment: Is the second view in a xib or storyboard? If yes, the view created in the first snippet is a completely different instance. Btw: `getValues` is a confusing name for a method which actually **sets** something.

Comment: @vadian: Both NSViews are separate classes in two files, which display in a .nib window (osx). I renamed the methods also to make it less confusing.

Comment: Then you need the actual reference to view 2 in the .nib for example with an `IBOutlet`. `[[NSViewTwo alloc] init]` creates a new (different) instance.

Comment: @vadian: What if though I just want to pass a value to a method in NSViewTwo, but that isn't part of the gui that it uses later?

Answer (score 0):

There is a misconception:

First of all action methods are an entry point from the GUI to your code, not an exit point. The passed value is always the sender. You can use action methods from your code, but this is rarely useful. So `-showValuesFromOne:` makes no sense at all.

Second, it is unusual to pass a value from a view to another view. View communicates with controllers and vice versa. Therefore the code in view 1 should be in the controller and be executed by the view 1. Then the invoked controller code pushes the values to view 2. Do not use a action method for this, but a simple method.

The controller loads both nibs and therefore has outlets to both views. Therefore for the controller it is easy to communicate with both views. The threads converge in his hand.

Comment: But I'm using a `void`, not an `IBAction`. I just need to get "a" (value) -> x into "b" (value) -> x.

Comment: What do you thing `IBAction` is? However, the array is not the sender.

Comment: I thought IBAction was to be used with IBOutlet, but that is just a guess. If NSArrary isn't the sender then what is? thanks.

Comment: It is an ordinary argument. Which introduction to Cocoa development did you read?